sap/hana-client library for node.js only works when user is logged in
I have a web server set up with node.js and express.
I use the sap/hana-client library for node.js to respond to requests by making queries.
This is a part of the code...

const hana = require('@sap/hana-client');
var connOptions = {
serverNode: '',
UID: '',
PWD: '',
ssValidateCertificate: 'true',
};
const server = express();
....etc
The code runs as a windows process.
Everything works perfectly while the user who owns the process is logged in.
If I close the user's session, the process continues working, listening to requests and making queries to SAP, but it returns this error:
Error: Connection failed (RTE:[1000013] The system cannot find the file specified.
If I log in to the server again with that user, it already makes the requests correctly.
I don't know if the user is not logged in and is trying to search for certificates or something.
Thanks!
It only works with the logged in user.
I have added log records and that error is what it returns.
Error: Connection failed (RTE:[1000013] The system cannot find the file specified.

I have tried another library, SAP/node-hdb: SAP HANA Database Client for Node, and to my surprise with the same configuration it does work with the user logged in and not logged in.
I'll leave this one.
